# Update the attributes of a java object from a thread?

Tags: java

The value of the variable var is always 0. IT is almost as if the method was never called. I would like to be able to change the value of val from inside the thread and if I call getVal() I would like to be able to have access to the new value.

```
public class Test1 {
    private int val;

    public Test1() {
        val=0;
    }

    public void changeVal() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                val=1;
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return this.val;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Test1 x=new Test1();
        x.changeVal();
        System.out.println("VAl: "+x.getVal() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the thread to start/complete before printing the value. [Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

Comment: `It is almost as if the method was never called`, that is a very accurate description of how cross-thread visibility can fail if your code isn't correctly synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

The value is changed, however getVal() is (most of the time) executed before var=1 in method 'run'. The order of execution is controled by thread scheduler, but as told by Johnny Mopp, adding .join() will fix it.

```
  public void changeVal() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                val = 1;

            }

        });
        t.start();
        t.join();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test1 x = new Test1();
        x.changeVal();

        System.out.println("VAl: " + x.getVal());
    }
```

Comment: Also mote how this essentially negates the need for another thread, as your code is now effectively single-threaded.

Comment: Agree, don't need to use another thread, but let us consider this as an exercise about concurrency

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a race condition between your statement

```
  x.changeVal();
```

and

```
 System.out.println("VAL: "+x.getVal() );
```

Try putting the following code between the above two statements.

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
```

This gives your new thread a chance to be established before you reach the println statement.

Comment: A chance it does give but a guarantee it does not.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your main method like below:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
 {
    Test1 x=new Test1();
    x.changeVal();
   try {
        Thread.sleep(100);//sometime here 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("VAl: "+x.getVal() );

 }
```

Or

You can use `Thread.join();` to join Main thread with child thread in `changeVal()` method.

Answer (score 0):

**One soultion could be use of ReentrantLock**

Define this as class member variable

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Use this lock in changeVal

```
public void changeVal() throws InterruptedException {
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    val = val + 1;
                }
            }).start();

        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the variable `volatile`, and you need to arrange some synchronization or locking if you want the variable to be changed before you print it in the main method. Which makes the thread completely pointless.

Hard to see the point of any of it really.